# How to rid of the "blinking" reloading effect of a Collapsible Menu?

Tags: jquery, html, css, sidebar

My boss would like a collapsible side bar for our website, which I have managed to come up with one.. However, she finds it annoying during navigation (or when the page is being refreshed) the side bar keeps reloading, and thus having this quick motion of collapsing and expanding (the "blinking") effect. Would it be possible to rid of it while still retain the function of the collapsible/ expandable function of the side bar?

Link: http://2ddige.com/temps/Services/proteomics%202d_dige.html

PS: She would like the default in the expanded state, not collapsed state.

```
Code:
// Appear/Disappear
            $('#menu4 > li > a.expanded + ul').show();
            $('#menu4 > li > a').click(function() {
                       $(this).toggleClass('expanded').toggleClass('collapsed').parent().find('> ul').toggle();
            });
            $('#example4 .expand_all').click(function() {
                $('#menu4 > li >   a.collapsed').addClass('expanded').removeClass('collapsed').parent().find('> ul').show();
            });
            $('#example4 .collapse_all').click(function() {
                $('#menu4 > li > a.expanded').addClass('collapsed').removeClass('expanded').parent().find('> ul').hide();
            });
```

Comment: Give it the classes for hidden in the html so that it is naturally collapsed or expanded before the javascript runs.

Comment: So I should add visibility: hidden? Sorry I am not very familiar with javascript..

Comment: No, Whatever classes are styling your collapsed thing should be added to the HTML so that it doesn't have to wait for javascript to execute to get formatting.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, it is already here: class "expanded" is controlling the expanded state.
<div id="leftnavi">
  <ul id="menu4" class="leftmenu">
   <li><a class="expanded">GEL-BASED PROTEOMICS</a>
  <ul>
   <li class="active"><a href="proteomics%202d_dige.html"><img alt="" height="9" src="../Images/boxes/crt_orange.gif" width="9" /> Global Protein Profiling</a>  </li>
 
   <li><a href="proteomics_PhosphoProtein.html"><img alt="" height="9" src="../Images/boxes/crt_orange.gif" width="9" /> Phosphorylated Protein Profiling</a></li>

... and so on

Comment: .leftmenu a.expanded {
   background: url('../Images/collapse2.png') no-repeat 50%;
   line-height: 35px;
   color: #333333;
   font-size: 11px;
   width: 243px;
   padding-left: 30px;
   

  }

Comment: Basically you have two options. Either stop reloading the page, or stop whatever javascript is causing the menu to blink. Does the menu blink at all if javascript doesn't touch it?

Comment: Not just reloading, even during navigation, the sidebar reloads itself on every page. If my boss had wanted the menu in collapsed state as a default, then that's ok. But she wants the menu to be in expanded state as a default, so the menu has to go through the motion of expanding itself to reach that default state on every page- resulting in the "blinking" effect. She wants the menu to be already expanded on every single page. We can't avoid the javascript because she wants the expandable/collapsible function.

Comment: Yes. when you navigate to another page, the page is reloading. It's the same thing! add `style="display: block"` to the stuff you want shown initially and remove `.show()` (the whole first line) outside of the event.

Comment: Right, that's why you need to add `style="display: block"` to the elements that the `.show()` would have affected, like i mentioned in that comment.

Comment: When I remove .show( ) (the whole first line)- the sidebar loaded in collapsed state. When I edited my html: <li><a class="expanded" style="display: block">GEL-BASED PROTEOMICS</a> The sidebar still has that blinking effect. When I did both, the sidebar still loaded in collapsed state.

Comment: You are adding the display:block to the wrong element, your selector targets sibling `ul` elements, not `a` elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the first line including .show() and either add this to your CSS:

```
#menu4 > li > a.expanded + ul {
    display: block;
}
```

or add this to each of those ul elements:

```
<ul style="display: block;">
```

What you are experiencing is known as a [FOUC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content), though that wiki doesn't mention that a FOUC can also happen when styling elements with javascript on page load or domcontentloaded.

Comment: Thanks alot Kevin for dealing patiently with an amateur like me, it worked! :-))) You are awesome!